# How to pull the index of an object from an array and its id in Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman, response

While the code itself looks like this:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var index = jsonData.findIndex(x => x.title==="Canary");
console.log(index);
pm.collectionVariables.set("school Index", index);

pm.collectionVariables.set("schoolId", jsonData[index].id);
```

With this response from the server:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "School 2",
    "foundationDate": "2021-10-30T00:00:00+03:00",
    "terminatedDate": null,
    "status": 1,
    "coursesCount": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Bitchip",
    "foundationDate": "2010-04-10T00:00:00+03:00",
    "terminatedDate": "2020-04-10T00:00:00+03:00",
    "status": 1,
    "coursesCount": 0
  }
]
```

BUT the task is like this - how to do the same thing, but through IF (by the "title" field to find the index and Id)?

A more detailed task - How to extract the ID and index for a course with a known Title from the response and set them as variables. There are two ways: the first through **Find (I used)**, the second through **if (I need to write)**

Comment: does it not help? https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

you need to get the id and index and then set them as variables (global, environment, or collection)

Comment: Sounds like whatever course you're doing wants you to iterate the array and check each value